# Bound ViewModel property not updating when clicking Clear All Button in TextBox

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've got a WinRT app (targeting 8.1+), and on one of my Pages, I've got several TextBoxes.  On these TextBoxes, I have handlers for GotFocus, LostFocus, KeyUp, KeyDown, and TextChanged, all of which do various things including calling another method which draws a graph based on the values in the TextBoxes.

This all works fine when the user is typing in the TextBoxes, however, there's a 'clear all button', which looks like a bold 'X' on the right side of the TextBox.  It's a nice feature; clicking it clears out the value of the TextBox.

When this button is clicked, however, the TwoWay binding of the value to the property in the ViewModel is not updated like it is when the user types in the TextBox.  Is there a way that I can force the bound value to update?  The ViewModel properties drive the graph, so when they're not updated, the graph doesn't update properly.

Here's the XAML for one of the TextBoxes:

```
    <TextBox 
        x:Name="y"  
        Text="{Binding YString,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Style="{StaticResource StatisticalPoint}"
        InputScope="CurrencyAmountAndSymbol"
        KeyDown="StatisticalValue_KeyDown"
        KeyUp="StatisticalValue_KeyUp"
        GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"
        LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
        TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
    />
```

Here's the TextBox_TextChanged implementation:

```
    protected void TextBox_TextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( sender is TextBox && ( (TextBox)sender ).Text.Length == 0 )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Value_Changed -- sender: {0}, e: {1}", sender, e);
            this.UpdateGraph();
        }
    }
```

*Update:* Interestingly, this problem only happens the *first* time you click the 'Clear All Button'.  If you hit the button, then type a value, the graph updates when you type the value, and then if you hit the button *again*, the graph updates properly from then on.

Comment: Note that in the TextBox_TextChanged, I *can* manually update the YString property to the `((TextBox)sender).Text`... but that's not entirely satisfying, as I feel like there should be an automatic, MVVM-style, way to have this work properly.

Comment: Hm, that's a weird one. Can you post the code attached to the Clear All button?

Comment: @KennyWyland This is indeed an odd bird. The "x" (clear all) button is built into the control. [See this MSDN page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.aspx) Hit control-f, search for "clear all". There doesn't appear to be a way to set the ICommand for it, that I saw. Please correct me if I'm wrong. [Relevant chat conversation is here.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/conversation/uwp-textbox-clear-all-button)

Comment: Can you provide a small working sample which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Do you call the PropertyChange on YString's setter?

Comment: @HosseinShahdoost, yes.  That's why setting the property in code-behind works.  I'm looking for a clear-all-button-specific Event that I can listen for, or some other way to make sure that the PropertyUpdated trigger fires when the Clear All Button is clicked.  Thanks for taking a look!